# Why does character of identity element always positive integer?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, characters

I'm a chemist who is interested in mathematics. One of the subject that I'm interested in is group theory and representation theory, because of its application in chemistry.

I was looking at character tables and realize that the characters of identity element is always a positive integer (i.e. in $Sym(3)$ the character for identity element is 1 and 2, in $Sym(4)$ the character for identity element is 1, 2, and 3, etc.).
Is there any reason for why this is true?

Comment: The character of the identity element is the trace of the identity matrix, i.e. the dimension (the "degree") of the representation.

Comment: The trace of the identity for any finite dimensional vector space is the sum of $1$s.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval Can you make that into an answer? Although it is trivial, we do not want answers to be lost in comments.

Comment: @Pedro Done. But can you please not delete your invitation? I do not want to be again accused of "low quality post".

Comment: @AnneBauval No problem.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't recovered yet from [having been insulted as "spam or rude or abusive" and censored](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4677260/386889) for a [short but honest answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4677260/3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The character of the identity element is the trace of the identity matrix, i.e. the dimension (the "degree") of the representation.

Comment: Upvoting this. We have likelyly handled this earlier, but it is not as frequent a duplicate as most others. And I don't have the time to search either :-)